# Get list of strings which matches my particular string?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of strings

`List<string> listOfstring = new List<string> { "a", "app", "1", "bam", "man","......."};//a big list`

now I need all the strings which start with `app` in linq

Comment: `listOfstring.Where(z => z?.StartsWith("app") == true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Where function in System.Linq is what you are looking for. We can also use the starts with function to get all values from your list that start with the word "app".

```
var results = listOfstring.Where(x => x.StartsWith("app", StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to write LINQ:
1. Query Syntax
2. Method Syntax

Using query syntax:

```
var results = from s in listOfstring where x.StartsWith("app") select s;
```

Using method syntax:

```
var results = listOfstring.Where(x=> x.StartsWith("app"));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this `listOfstring.Where(x => x.StartsWith("app"))`